# CartWidget to show products on hover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover, jsx, cart

I have a cartwidget that i would like to show the items that are already in the cart when I put the mouse on the CartWidget. I do not kow how to implement this code. I just create a CartHover component with  function and the Cart.js component inside of it. Then, I added CartHover in the CartWidget. But, nothing happened. Maybe there is someone that can help me and do the hover on the cartWidget in another way.
This is the CartHover:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import CartComponent from "../Cart/Cart";

const CartHover = () => {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const showCart = (e)=>{
        setShow(!show);
    };
    const hideCart = e => {
        setShow(false);
    };
    return (
        <>
        <div>
            <CartComponent
            show={show}
            onMouseEnter={showCart} 
            onMouseLeave={hideCart}/>
        </div>
        </>
    )
};
export default CartHover;
```

This is the Cart.jsx where are all the items in the shopping-cart and I want to be seen in the hover, perhaps it is necessary to do a smaller version of it:

```
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCartContext } from "../../Context/CartContext";

const CartComponent = () => {
  const { list, totalPrice, deleteProd } = useCartContext();
    return (
      <>
      <h1 className="py-4 text-center text-muted">
        Cart
      </h1>
      {list.length > 0 ? (<Table striped hover className="text-muted">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Product</th>
              <th>Title</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
              <th>Price</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {list.map((varietal) => (
              <tr key={varietal.id}>
                <td>
                  <img
                    src={varietal.pictureUrl}
                    alt='img'
                    style={{ width: "82px" }}
                  />
                </td>
                <td className="align-middle">{varietal.title}</td>                
                <td className="align-middle">{varietal.count}</td>
                <td className="align-middle">${varietal.price}</td>
                <td className="align-middle"><button onClick={() => deleteProd(varietal)} className="badge badge-info">Remove</button></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
          <thead>
            <tr className="font-weight-bold">
              <td colSpan="3">Total</td>
              <td>${totalPrice()}</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </Table>) : (<div className="py-5">
            <h3 className="d-flex justify-content-center pt-5 text-muted">The Cart is empty</h3>
            <p className="d-flex justify-content-center text-muted">
              Return to home to see our products
            </p>
            <Link to='/' className="d-flex justify-content-center text-decoration-none"><button className="btn btn-info"> Home </button></Link>
        </div>)}
        </>
    );
  };

export default CartComponent;
```

This is the NavBar:

```
import React from "react";
import { Navbar as NavbarBootstrap, Nav } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import CartHover from "../CartHover/CartHover";
import CartWidgetComponet from "../CartWidget/CartWidget";
import LogoComponent from "../Logo/LogoComponent";

const NavBar = () => (
  <>
    <NavbarBootstrap bg="light" variant="light">        
        <Link to="/" className="text-decoration-none">
            <NavbarBootstrap.Brand className="mx-5 px-5"><LogoComponent /> AIMARA</NavbarBootstrap.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Nav className="ml-auto">
            <Link to="/" className="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Aimara</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/category/red" className="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Red Wines</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/category/white" className="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <Nav className="mx-3">White Wines</Nav>
            </Link>
            <Link to="/Contact" className="text-decoration-none text-dark">
                <Nav className="mx-3">Contact</Nav>
            </Link>
        </Nav>
        <NavLink to="/Cart" className="pl-3 pr-1 text-muted"><CartWidgetComponet><CartHover /></CartWidgetComponet></NavLink>
    </NavbarBootstrap>
  </>
);

export default NavBar;
```

and this is the CartWidgetComponent:

```
import { useCartContext } from "../../Context/CartContext";

const CartWidgetComponet = () => {
  const { list, totalQuantity } = useCartContext();
  return (
    <>
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="25" height="25" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-cart2" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
        <path d="M0 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 2H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 4H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1.5 6A.5.5 0 0 1 13 11H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485-.379L1.61 3H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.14 5l1.25 5h8.22l1.25-5H3.14zM5 13a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zm9-1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0z"/>
      </svg>
      {list.length > 0 ? (<span className="badge badge-info">{totalQuantity()}</span>) : null}
    </>
  );
};

export default CartWidgetComponet;
```

I hope there is someone that could help me. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using React Boostrap. It has `OverlayTrigger` that you can put to use in this case. The idea is to make your `CartHover` element a popover for the `OverlayTrigger` so that whatever triggers it (hover in our case) shows your `CardHover` elements. So here is some code:

```
const CartHover = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        You have x number of items in your cart and here they are
        <br />
        Item 1
        <br />
        Item 2
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const CartIcon = () => {
  const popover = (
    <Popover>
      <Popover.Content>
        <CartHover />
      </Popover.Content>
    </Popover>
  );

  return (
    <OverlayTrigger
      trigger={["click", "hover"]}
      rootClose={true}
      placement={"bottom"}
      overlay={popover}
    >
      <div className={"d-inline-block"}>
        <svg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          width="25"
          height="25"
          fill="currentColor"
          className="bi bi-cart2"
          viewBox="0 0 16 16"
        >
          <path d="M0 2.5A.5.5 0 0 1 .5 2H2a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.379L2.89 4H14.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .485.621l-1.5 6A.5.5 0 0 1 13 11H4a.5.5 0 0 1-.485-.379L1.61 3H.5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM3.14 5l1.25 5h8.22l1.25-5H3.14zM5 13a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0zm9-1a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2zm-2 1a2 2 0 1 1 4 0 2 2 0 0 1-4 0z" />
        </svg>
        <span className="badge badge-info">8</span>
      </div>
    </OverlayTrigger>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CartIcon />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-shape-ow5wz?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the cartContext or the cartWidget look like. But it looks to me like some code is missing here to really see what you'd need to do to get it working. Specifically, I don't see the piece that uses the show property to determine where or not to display the cart within the Cart component.

https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-bogdan-fd5t1?file=/src/CartComponent.js